# Network not working on ubuntu/virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I had network connectivity working in ubuntu 12 under virtual box.

I issued the commands

> sudo ifdown eth0
>   sudo ifup eth0

and now ubuntu no longer can connect to the internet. I'm not very familiar with this. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   sudo ifconfig eth0 down
   sudo ifconfig eth0 up
   sudo dhclient eth0
```

Otherwise, turning the VM iff and then back on will  do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So far, it's not working yet...

Comment: @user186873 please tell us what hypervisor you are using, whether NAT/bridge/host-only/internal, post output of ifconfig -a, route -n.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing the following?

```
sudo service network restart
```

Comment: While it didn't work, according to the original poster, it was an answer.  I suppose I should have phrased it as:

"Try doing a 'sudo service network restart' to force a reset of the entire networking stack."

Comment: To follow up on the original post ...

Some more information would be helpful.  What is the host operating system?  What version of VirtualBox are you using?  Do you have any other virtual machines on the system?  If so, does the networking work on them?